# select top 1 in subquery?

Tags: sql, sybase

I'm trying to get a top 1 returned for each code in this query but this is giving me syntax errors. Any ideas what I can do?

```
SELECT d.doc_no,
       d.doc_short_name,
       d.doc_name,
       r.revision_code,
       r.revision,
       r.description,
       dtg.group_name,
  (SELECT top 1 di.index_user_id
   FROM document_instance
   WHERE doc_no = d.doc_no
   ORDER BY entry_time DESC) AS 'last indexed by'
FROM documents d
LEFT JOIN document_revision r ON r.doc_no = d.doc_no
LEFT JOIN document_instance di ON di.doc_no = d.doc_no
LEFT JOIN document_type_group dtg ON dtg.doc_no = d.doc_no
```

Comment: `di.index_user_id` there is no alias for `di`, actually its in the outer reference.

Comment: Do the sub query in a left join, then select the value from the left join.

Comment: I think you just need to remove `di.` from the subquery column you are trying to get.

Comment: even if I change that I get incorrect syntax near the keyword top

Comment: if I do a sub query I need to order everything by entry_time desc and then group. So, user1 10/10/1980 user 1 10/10/2017 user2 10/10/2000 user 2 10/10/2017 becomes 2 rows with the latest dates for each code.This gives 1 row only: select top 1 index_user_id, doc_no 
from document_instance
group by index_user_id, doc_no
order by entry_time desc

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sybase DBMS DBMS

Comment: This i the sub query / join gives me only 1 row: select top 1 index_user_id, doc_no from document_instance group by index_user_id, doc_no order by entry_time desc

Comment: what syntax errors exactly are you getting?

Comment: incorrect syntax near top. It doesn;t like the top in the subquery

Comment: not familiar with sybase, but does this solve your issue? http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1653299-Sybase-Top-N-in-Subquery-equivalent

Comment: Where's your `sybase` tag???  It's useless if someone give you query for Mysql or Oracle.  So tag properly.

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?) and version?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Sybase ASE, the `top #` clause is only supported in derived tables, ie, it's not supported in correlated sub-queries like you're attempting.

Also note that `order by` is not supported in any sub-queries (derived table or correlated).

If I'm reading the query correctly, you want the `index_user_id` for the record with the `max(entry_time)`; if this is correct, and assuming a single record is returned for a given `doc_no/entry_time` combo, you could try something like:

```
SELECT d.doc_no,
       d.doc_short_name,
       d.doc_name,
       r.revision_code,
       r.revision,
       r.description,
       dtg.group_name,

       (SELECT d2.index_user_id
        FROM   document_instance d2
        WHERE  d2.doc_no     = d1.doc_no
        and    d2.entry_time = (select max(d3.entry_time)
                                from   document_instance d3
                                where  d3.doc_no = d1.doc_no)
       ) as 'last indexed by'

FROM      documents d
LEFT JOIN document_revision r     ON   r.doc_no = d.doc_no
LEFT JOIN document_instance d1    ON  d1.doc_no = d.doc_no
LEFT JOIN document_type_group dtg ON dtg.doc_no = d.doc_no
```